# Error in update method

Tags: symfony

i have an error in miseAjour method i can't find the solution

here is the error:
Controller "Team\ManagerBundle\Controller\PlayerController::miseAjourAction()" requires that you provide a value for the "$id" argument (because there is no default value or because there is a non optional argument after this one).

here is the code of miseAjourAction:

public function miseAjourAction($id){

```
$em = $this->container->get('doctrine')->getEntityManager();
$Player = $em->getRepository('TeamManagerBundle:Player')->find($id);
$form = $this->createform(new PlayerForm(),$Player);

$request = $this->getRequest();

if($request->getMethod() == 'POST'){
    $form->bind($request);
    if($form->isValid()){

        $em = $this->container->get('Doctrine')->getEntityManager();
        $em->persist($Player);
        $em->flush();


        return $this->render('TeamManagerBundle:Player:succes.html.twig',array('msg'=>'Mise à jour effectué avec succés'));
    }
}
return $this->render('TeamManagerBundle:Player:miseajour.html.twig',array('Form'=>$form->createView()));


    }
```

Comment: This is a simple routing issue.  Probably just need to add $id = null in your controller method.  Or set a default in your route definition.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem could be the same as your last post: It's better to use `findOneById()` in your repository (and throw an exception if you have no result). Try with this kind of code and tell us if it solves your problem.

```
public function miseAjourAction($id)
{
    $em = $this->getDoctrine()->getEntityManager();

    $player = $em->getRepository('TeamManagerBundle:Player')->findOneById($id);

    if (!$player) {
        throw $this->createNotFoundException('No player found for id '.$id);
    } 

    $form = $this->createform(new PlayerForm(), $player);

    $form->handleRequest($request);

    if ($form->isValid()) {
        $em->persist($player);
        $em->flush();

        return $this->render('TeamManagerBundle:Player:succes.html.twig',array('msg'=>'Mise à jour effectué avec succés'));
    }

    return $this->render('TeamManagerBundle:Player:miseajour.html.twig',array('Form'=>$form->createView()));
}
```

Comment: Why do keep recommending findOneById over find?  They are functionality equivalent though the findOneById is a bit slower and requires that your primary key be actually named 'id'.

Comment: i found the problem it was from the routing
it was
team_manager_MAJ_player:
    path: /miseAjour/
    defaults: { _controller: TeamManagerBundle:Player:miseAjour }
    

i changed the path to : path: /miseAjour/{id}